# Are Static variables in functions initialized as NULL (manual)?

Tags: php, variables, static

I know they are, the long version of the question is:

Where in the PHP manual is it stated that static function variables are initialized to NULL and considered empty?

```
<?php
function foo() {
    static $static;
}
```

Example: Inside foo, to which value is $static initialized on first call?

I remember that this was written in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) but I did not bookmark the location. Over the last three days I tried to find it again but no luck.

I'm looking for a document with authority, so the statement can be stressed for. For example a page in the PHP manual that is making clear which values those initialized to if none specified, unfortunately, [Using static variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) in the manual is not giving any information about this.
A proof based on [on the source-code of the PHP language](http://php.net/downloads.php) (not a PHP script) would be sufficient as well, I'm still not good at reading the PHP sourcecode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php:

> A variable is considered to be null
>   if:
>
> - it has been assigned the constant NULL.
> - it has not been set to any value yet.
> - it has been unset().

Since a static variable is a variable, then the above (second point) sufficiently answers your question. The burden of proof is now on someone to show that the manual states that static variables behave differently.

I think one will be disappointed if he expects the manual to have a special section for every type of variable explaining in duplicate fashion how each work exactly the same way regarding initialization, casting, mathematical operations, etc.

Comment: I think that was the page I've been looking for. Thanks a lot, I was so much searching for the static keyword that I must have overlooked it. I knew it was there! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php and scroll down to 
*Example #1 Default values of uninitialized variables*.  You will see it explains

> Unset AND unreferenced (no use
>   context) variable; outputs NULL

Comment: That part of the documentation is not referring to static variables, it's about variables in general. The example you pick is especially about a variable that is undefined (unset). static variables are defined, so they differ from that (e.g. give no warnings).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a document with authority

You don't need no *steenking* document.  Try *testing the code*.  From PHP's interactive shell:

```
php > function foo() { static $bar; var_export($bar); }
php > foo();
NULL
```

Thus we know that at least as of PHP 5.3, **static variables work just like normal variables: they are `null` until given a value**.

What did you expect?  Why are you asking this question?  Are you getting weird behavior?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As written in my question, I know that it is NULL. Less than a technical issue, this is a documentation issue to me. PHP 5.3 is not a full PHP version identification, with which version exactly did you made that test?

Comment: I tested this in 5.3.3 above, and have also verified this behavior on 5.0.4 (ewwwwwwww) and 5.2.6 (eww).  I'll ask again: **What did you expect? Why are you asking this question? Are you getting weird behavior?**  While they used to frequently change random behavior in the 4.x days, they've done a [thorough job documenting 5.x behavior changes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php).

Comment: Thanks Charles for the additional information. I personally do not get different behavior. I just need the specification in documentation, that's all I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there's really one one implementation of PHP out there, you could take any proof-of-concept script and take its output as the "definitive" proof:

```
marc@panic:~$ cat z.php
<?php

function foo() {
        static $bar;
        var_dump($bar);
}

foo();
marc@panic:~$ php z.php
NULL
```

so, yes, it would appear that declared-but-not-explicitly-initialized static vars are assigned the NULL value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As written in my question, I know that it is NULL. Less than a technical issue, this is a documentation issue to me. Looks like I did not made that clear enough so far in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are initialized to null.

```
class MyClass {
    static $var;
}

var_dump(MyClass::$var); // returns NULL
```

Comment: He's referring to static variables inside of functions, not classes.

Comment: There's no difference. It's also the same as saying `$var;` All variables that are declared but not assigned a value are null.